# how do i add all the elements of the for loop?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int even_numbers_sum(){
    int d;
    for(d=0;d<=100;d++){
        if(d%2==0){
            printf("\n this is even number loop %d",d);
        }
    }
    int sum;
    sum=sum+d;
    printf("\n the value of total sum of the loop %d",sum);
    return sum;
}
int main(){
    even_numbers_sum();
}
```

my main aim is to calculate the sum of all the elemets of for loop i took a for loop and described its value and put a equation (if) to pass anynumber if its only even other wise it will not work and i have to add all those even number till 100 how do i do it

Comment: How would you calculate the sum on pen and paper or with a calculator...?

Comment: declare this `int sum;` at the start of function `even_numbers_sum` and this `sum=sum+d;` inside the `if` condition.

Comment: You need to define *and initialise* `int sum = 0` before the loop begins.

Answer (score 1):

Initialised sum to 0 at the beginning. Changed the return type of the function to void as int was unnecessary. Sum has to be incremented in the if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void even_numbers_sum(){
    int d;
    int sum=0;
    for(d=0;d<=100;d++){
        if(d%2==0){
            printf("\n this is even number loop %d",d);
            sum=sum+d;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the value of total sum of the loop %d",sum);
}
int main(){
    even_numbers_sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look the following code. I've written this code for any number if you want to change the upper bound instead of 100 , you just have to pass the integer to the function i.e. if you want to get the sum of all even integers from 0 to 100, you have to pass 100 while calling the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void even_numbers_sum(int i){
    int d;
    int sum=0;
    for(d=0;d<=i;d+=2){
            printf("\n this is even number loop %d",d);
            sum=sum+d;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the value of total sum of the loop %d",sum);
}
int main(){
    even_numbers_sum(100);
    return 0;
}
```

1.first change is here in function declaration and definition you have to write `int i` in the parentheses.

```
void even_numbers_sum(int i)
```

2.Secondly there is no need to put the condition if you want to start from 0. it can be done by simply increment d by 2.
for(d=0;d<=i;d+=2)

3.Your main method has return type `int` so there should be some integer returned.

```
return 0;
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem. If there is anything which you want to ask I'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should initialize `sum` as 0 at begin. `sum` may be not 0 without initialization.

Secondly, in your code, `sum` will be only add with the final even number (100), not add each each even number from 0 to 100.

A correct example as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int even_numbers_sum()
{
    int d, sum = 0; // initialize sum as 0
    for (d = 0; d <= 100; d++) {
        if (d % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n this is even number loop %d", d);
            sum = sum + d; // add each even number to sum
        }
    }
    // sum=sum+d; // This line code will add final even number and sum
    printf("\n the value of total sum of the loop %d", sum);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    even_numbers_sum();
}
```